# BackgroundColor in control blocked click

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I have **Frame** with **Grid** in content. When i added **contentWiew** (with content) to **Grid** there are two options:

**1.** If **contentWiew** have BackgroundColor = "**Transparent**" then when i click to the  **contentWiew**  pressing happen in **Frame** (contentWiew  skiped through it).

**2.** If **contentWiew** have BackgroundColor = **NotTransparent** (Red,Yellow) then when i click to the  **contentWiew**  pressing happen in **contentWiew** ().

Part of the code:

```
        Label mainText = new Label {  Text = "TestText", FontSize = 14 };
        var contntView = new ContentView () { BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent , HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start };
        contntView.Content =  mainText;
        mainGrid.Children.Add (contntView,0,1);
```

I need to do exactly the turnover =) When ContentView is **Transparent** - catch click.  When ContentView is **not Transparent** - skip click to Frame.

How can I control this process, regardless of BackgroundColor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can partially control this process using any View's `InputTransparent` property. If it's set to `true`, the view will be transparent to touch events.

Comment: For the first embodiment i set property "BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgba(1,1,1,0); "
For the second embodiment i set property "InputTransparent   = true".
Perfect! Thanks!